# How the proper way to explode array from database make it as option in dropdown in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html

i have array, and want to explode the array as option in dropdown, here is the table

```
id          value           option
K1          1,2,3        AAA,BBB,CCC
K2          1,2,3        DDD,EEE,FFF
```

i want the output like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="val[]">Parameter K1</label>';
<select class="form-control" name="val[]">
<option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Choose one</option>
<option value="1">AAA</option>
<option value="2">BBB</option>
<option value="3">CCC</option>                                          
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="val[]">Parameter K2</label>';
<select class="form-control" name="val[]">
<option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Choose one</option>
<option value="1">DDD</option>
<option value="2">EEE</option>
<option value="3">FFF</option>                                          
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: The *proper* way is not to store CSV in a database column.  It would be better to normalize your database.

Comment: To explode string use `explode(',', $rowValue)`. But as @NigelRen told - your DB structure is wrong

Comment: so how the correct DB structure? is it like this?

Comment: id         value        option
K1          1            AAA
K1          2            BBB
K1          3            CCC
K2          1            DDD
K2          2            EEE
K2          3            FFF

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to suppress the data in a table with php in this way.

I wrote a mysqli query for you, it's `$query` variable.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl_variables");
```

Then I wrote this query with the `while` loop with the help of `mysqli_fetch_object` and read it line by line.

```
<?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
                echo '

                <option value="'?><?php echo $row->optionValue; ?><?php echo'">'?><?php echo $row->optionText; ?><?php echo'</option>

                ';

            }

            ?>
```

All code parts;

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl_variables");


?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="val[]">Parameter K1</label>';
    <select class="form-control" name="val[]">
        <option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Choose one</option>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
            echo '

            <option value="'?><?php echo $row->optionValue; ?><?php echo'">'?><?php echo $row->optionText; ?><?php echo'</option>

            ';

        }

        ?>

    </select>
</div>
```